# Hyperledger Fabric System Chaincode Plugin - missing sample

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

according to the system chaincode documentation located at:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/systemchaincode.html

there should be a sample at the repository:

"Every system chaincode must implement the Chaincode Interface and export a constructor method that matches the signature func New() shim.Chaincode in the main package. An example can be found in the repository at examples/plugin/scc."

yet the folder examples/plugin/scc is not present anywhere on github fabric repository ...

can someone please point me in the right direction? thanks

*EDIT*

the only sample i found is

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release/core/scc/samplesyscc

is this the sample the documentation is refering to? if yes, maybe update your documentation ...

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact there is no big difference between implementing a regular chaincode and the system chaincode. The only difference is that system chaincode is compiled into the peer and run inside peer process or could be turned on as a [plugging](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/).

So, yes example you have found is the one you can use to implement system chaincode on your own, e.g. https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/scc/samplesyscc/samplesyscc.go.

Moreover you can take a look on other system chaincode to get more general idea, for example you can learn from [QSCC](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/core/scc/qscc/query.go#L40) (Query System ChainCode).

In order to enable system chaincode you need to make sure to enable it inside `core.yaml` file for example this is how it looks like for system chaincode compiled into peer code:

```
# system chaincodes whitelist. To add system chaincode "myscc" to the
# whitelist, add "myscc: enable" to the list below, and register in
# chaincode/importsysccs.go
system:
    cscc: enable
    lscc: enable
    escc: enable
    vscc: enable
    qscc: enable
    rscc: disable
```

in addition you need to list inside `importsysccs.go`, e.g.:

```
var systemChaincodes = []*SystemChaincode{
    {
        Enabled:           true,
        Name:              "cscc",
        Path:              "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/cscc",
        InitArgs:          [][]byte{[]byte("")},
        Chaincode:         &cscc.PeerConfiger{},
        InvokableExternal: true, // cscc is invoked to join a channel
    },
    {
        Enabled:           true,
        Name:              "lscc",
        Path:              "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/lscc",
        InitArgs:          [][]byte{[]byte("")},
        Chaincode:         lscc.NewLifeCycleSysCC(),
        InvokableExternal: true, // lscc is invoked to deploy new chaincodes
        InvokableCC2CC:    true, // lscc can be invoked by other chaincodes
    },
    {
        Enabled:   true,
        Name:      "escc",
        Path:      "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/escc",
        InitArgs:  [][]byte{[]byte("")},
        Chaincode: &escc.EndorserOneValidSignature{},
    },
    {
        Enabled:   true,
        Name:      "vscc",
        Path:      "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/scc/vscc",
        InitArgs:  [][]byte{[]byte("")},
        Chaincode: &vscc.ValidatorOneValidSignature{},
    },
    {
        Enabled:           true,
        Name:              "qscc",
        Path:              "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/qscc",
        InitArgs:          [][]byte{[]byte("")},
        Chaincode:         &qscc.LedgerQuerier{},
        InvokableExternal: true, // qscc can be invoked to retrieve blocks
        InvokableCC2CC:    true, // qscc can be invoked to retrieve blocks also by a cc
    },
    {
        Enabled:           true,
        Name:              "rscc",
        Path:              "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/rscc",
        InitArgs:          [][]byte{[]byte("")},
        Chaincode:         rscc.NewRscc(),
        InvokableExternal: true,  // rscc can be invoked to update policies
        InvokableCC2CC:    false, // rscc cannot be invoked from a cc
    },
}
```

as alternative you can have your system chaincode as plugin, to enable it you need to setup it within `core.yaml`:

```
# System chaincode plugins: in addition to being imported and compiled
# into fabric through core/chaincode/importsysccs.go, system chaincodes
# can also be loaded as shared objects compiled as Go plugins.
# See examples/plugins/scc for an example.
# Like regular system chaincodes, plugins must also be white listed in the
# chaincode.system section above.
systemPlugins:
  # example configuration:
  # - enabled: true
  #   name: myscc
  #   path: /opt/lib/myscc.so
  #   invokableExternal: true
  #   invokableCC2CC: true
```

Comment: In which directory importsysccs.go resides?

Comment: If you searched in the code base, you should find it at here: `core/scc/importsysccs.go`

Answer (score 0):

Note that as of Fabric v2.0 system chaincode plugin support has been removed. Here is the release note from v2.0:

> As part of a general move away from go plugins as an extension
> mechanism for Fabric, the ability to add system chaincodes via go
> plugins has been removed. Users wishing to extend Fabric with custom
> system chaincodes may rebuild the peer binary with the system
> chaincode built into the binary. This system chaincode should then be
> defined and initialized like any other user chaincode would be. This
> new model is very similar to the plugin model (which required that the
> plugin to be built at the same exact commit of Fabric), and addresses
> the significant shortcomings around the lifecycle and validation of
> system chaincode transactions.

It is still possible to build a system chaincode into the peer binary/image. You can inspect [internal/peer/node/start.go](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/main/internal/peer/node/start.go) and search for a system chaincode like `qscc` as a reference example of how a system chaincode gets registered, and then extend the peer start code to include the new system chaincode in the same way.

You will also need to add the system chaincode to `core.yaml` `chaincode.system` property to ensure it is enabled on the peer at runtime.