# How can I deploy my own system chaincode in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to install and deploy my own system chaincode in hyperledger fabric. I'm using v1.3. I came across this answer [Hyperledger Fabric System Chaincode Plugin - missing sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069094/hyperledger-fabric-system-chaincode-plugin-missing-sample). But it's specific to v1.1 and now `importsyscss.go` looks very different.

I tried to follow the procedure mentioned in the above link but it didn't work out for me.

I copied `myscc.so` file in `/opt/lib/`. Made an entry `myscc: enable` in `core.yaml` as well.

Uncommented

```
example configuration:                                                                    
  - enabled: true
    name: myscc
    path: /opt/lib/myscc.so
    invokableExternal: true
    invokableCC2CC: true
```

`docker restart peer0.org1.example.com
 docker logs peer0.org1.example.com`

Everything runs perfectly without any error but still, I don't see logs with `myscc` mentioned anywehere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCC plugins were disabled, but they added a secret flag to allow this for faster development.

The peer has to be built with the following flags:

```
GO_TAGS+=" pluginsenabled" make peer
```

End-to-End tests utilize docker containers hence the containers should also be built with

```
DOCKER_DYNAMIC_LINK=true GO_TAGS+=" pluginsenabled" make peer-docker
```